# Is there a way to increase the font size for .facet in Altair without specifying rows or columns?

Tags: fonts, font-size, altair

I want to use the wrap around function for .facet in altair since I  have a lot of variables. However, when I do so, all the labels are so small. All the suggestions I've seen for increasing the size involve breaking things into rows or columns, which if I try to do, I lose my wrap around functionality.

For example, I would like to make the years in the below graph a larger font. Any ideas?

[Example image that I would like to modify][1]

````
source = data.population()

alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('age:O'),
    alt.Y(
        'sum(people):Q',
    ),
).properties(
    title='US Age Distribution By Year',
    width=90,
    height=80
).facet('year:O', columns=5)```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHfJm.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```py
alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('age:O'),
    alt.Y(
        'sum(people):Q',
    ),
).properties(
    title='US Age Distribution By Year',
    width=90,
    height=80
).facet(
    facet=alt.Facet('year:O', header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=16)),
    columns=5
)
```